# How Convert hex ip from Java?

Tags: ip, converters

i used `cat /proc/pid/net/udp6` and become:
`sl  local_address                         remote_address                        st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode ref pointer drops
  63: 00000000000000000000000000000000:D9BF 00000000000000000000000000000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 181584 2 c16e8d00 0`

I know how its structured and the `00000000000000000000000000000000:D9BF`must be local ip. How can I convert it to normal ip format like 127.0.0.1?

Comment: oh, i mean 127.0.0.1. Yes I know, but i want convert it to a int format of ip adress. Just hex to int format and not IPv6 to IPv4

Comment: You'd neet a `uint128_t` - or maybe better a `char[16]`...

Comment: ok, but how can I convert it then?

Comment: ok, but how can i convert it then?

Answer (score 1):

```
InetAddress a = InetAddress.getByAddress(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("0A064156"));
```